# How to Share Analysis Services Data Sources Across a Team

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We develop an application which uses MSSQL Server. For development purposes everybody uses local servers.

I created a new Analysis Services Project and added data source do the Data Sources folder. I selected my local server named **MYNAME-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSRV** and it works for me.

After I commited that and my colleague pulled it (we use git) there is no data source under Data Sources folder for him. Which was by the way quite predictable.

The question is how to make it work for everybody?